# How to check a record returned in py2neo is null?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I want to check if a node already exist in neo4j. I use the following code:

```
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo import *
authenticate("localhost:7474","neo4j", "somepassword")
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE(alice:Person {name:'Alice' , age:15})->[:Friendof]->(bob:Person {name: 'Bob' , age:14})")
for record in graph.cypher.execute("MATCH(p {title:'The Movie'})RETURN p"):
    if (record[0]==None):
        print "None"
    else:
        print (record[0])
```

I dont have a movie with title 'The Movie', but i dont get "None" printed. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Not related but if you're doing `from py2neo import Graph` and then `from py2neo import *`, the second import on it's own would import `Graph`. So just the 2nd one is enough [but considered not good](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/1431750).

Answer (score 2):

"None" isn't printed because there are no records to iterate through so the print statement isn't executed.

Instead you can check if there are any records returned:

```
results = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (p:Movie {title:'The Movie'}) RETURN p")
if results:
    for record in results:
        # do something with each record...
else:
    print "None"
```

Comment: You have that backward, should be `if not results`.